# Scrapy Item Pipelines not enabled on PythonAnywhere.com

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, scrapy, pythonanywhere

I deployed a scrappy/flask project on PythonAnywhere.com (PA) that works on my local machine and almost entirely works on PA. The issue I have is that when I schedule a task to run my spider, no pipelines are enabled. This is obviously an issue as my MongoDB and images pipelines will not update. Any ideas as to why I am having this issue and how to resolve it? I am able to query MongoDB and my site renders as expected, it's just that no pipelines are enabled during a crawl so I am left with an outdated site. Upon closer inspection, it appears that the crawler uses an incorrect bot. See the following outputs; the first from my local machine and the second from PA:

Correct - my local machine:

```
2019-03-16 15:51:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: mycorrectbot)
2019-03-16 15:51:12 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.1 (default, Nov 28 2018, 11:51:47) - [Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
2019-03-16 15:51:12 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'mycorrectbot', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'mine.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['mine.spiders'], 'USER_AGENT': 'mine (+https://mine.com)'}
```

Incorrect - on PA:

```
2019-03-16 22:57:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.6.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2019-03-16 22:57:11 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 20:50:05) - [GCC 5.4.0 20160609], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.4.0-1075-aws-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
2019-03-16 22:57:11 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
```

Structure of project:

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── flask_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── flask_app.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── home.css
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── full
│   │   │       ├── 1.jpg
│   │   │       ├── 2.jpg
│   │   │       ├── 3.jpg
│   │   └── vendor
│   │       ├── bootstrap
│   │       │   ├── css
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap.css
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   │       │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │       │   │   └── bootstrap.min.css.map
│   │       │   └── js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.bundle.js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.bundle.js.map
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.js
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.js.map
│   │       │       ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │       │       └── bootstrap.min.js.map
│   │       └── jquery
│   │           ├── jquery.js
│   │           ├── jquery.min.js
│   │           ├── jquery.min.map
│   │           ├── jquery.slim.js
│   │           ├── jquery.slim.min.js
│   │           └── jquery.slim.min.map
│   └── templates
│       └── index.html
├── scrapy_app
│   ├── scrapy_app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── items.py
│   │   ├── middlewares.py
│   │   ├── pipelines.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   └── spiders
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── mine.py
│   └── scrapy.cfg
└── requirements.txt
```

It is my understanding that I am unable to call the .py for my scrapy spider in PA Tasks directly and must instead rely on a separate file to make the "scrapy crawl my spider" call I would normally make. However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. I referenced, this [doc page](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-from-script) but I must be missing something.

Here is the file I created to make the alternate call and point to in PA Task:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy_app.spiders import mine

class MySpider('my spider'):
    # Your spider definition
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl(mine.MySpider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

The following is the scheduled task I added on PA (not in project structure - please disregard this fact):

```
/home/myuserid/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/bin/python /home/myuserid/flask_app/flask_app/scheduler.py
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I made this far more complicated than I needed. The only variance between my PA and local app was the type of Virtual Environment I was running. I deleted the recommended VE on PA and instead used venv. I then wrote a simple script to activate the VE, run my spider, and then deactivate. Script as follows (scheduler.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~
source myvenv/bin/activate
cd /home/userid/project/scrapy_app/scrapy_app
scrapy crawl my spider
deactivate
```

All now works as expected despite the terrible guidance on both PA and scrapy. Hope this helps someone else!